# Using 'Do' or 'Does' in the sentence below?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

in the sentence:

> The chart signs (A-G) are matched with the map signs and so 'do or does' the color map?

must we use do or does?

Comment: How would you use do and does in a sentence? How do you determine which to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.   The word you want is "are".   My best guess for your intended meaning is:

> The chart signs (A-G) **are** matched with the map signs, and so **are** the colors.

which carries the same semantics as

> The chart signs (A-G) **are** *matched with the map signs*, and the colors **are** [also] *matched with the map signs*.

Trying to switch from "are matched" to "do match" breaks the parallel structure, which results in a sentence that's more difficult to understand.

This longer paraphrasing of the sentence makes the role of "the colors" more obvious.   It is the subject of the second "are".   We use "are" because this subject is plural.   A singular third-person subject would require "is":

> The chart *signs* (A-G) **are** matched with the map signs, and so **is** the *shading*.